# How can I capture the dynamic text from regex in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

```
import re
see = """https://www.flipkart.com/honor-7c-blue-64-gb/p/itmfaybh5jjzhmpz?pid=MOBF3T87CECXMZQH&lid=LSTMOBF3T87CECXMZQHFPGOZQ&marketplace=FLIPKART","name":"Honor 7C (Blue, 64 GB)"},{"@type":"ListItem","position":2,"url":"https://www.flipkart.com/honor-7c-blue-32-gb/p/itmf53qmmggh2ynj?pid=MOBF3T87QFSQXGCM&lid=LSTMOBF3T87QFSQXGCMUHVDHM&marketplace=FLIPKART","name":"Honor 7C (Blue, 32 GB)"},{"@type":"ListItem","position":3,"url":"https://www.flipkart.com/honor-7c-black-32-gb/p/itmf5ch2zb97avvz?pid=MOBF3T877EEKFWGN&lid=LSTMOBF3T877EEKFWGN9WQ3A4&marketplace=FLIPKART","name":"Honor 7C (Black, 32 GB)"},{"@type":"ListItem","position":4,"url":"https://www.flipkart.com/honor-8c-black-64-gb/p/itmfc8c4fsekrpdp?pid=MOBFC8C8FXXNHZ7C&lid=LSTMOBFC8C8FXXNHZ7CZYQGKP&marketplace=FLIPKART"""
regex = r'\"position":2,\"url\":\",\"name\":\"(.*)\"'
match = re.findall(regex, see)

print(match)
```

I want to capture just the names from the above variable the output must be in this way -
(Honor 7C (Blue, 64 GB),Honor 7C (Blue, 32 GB),Honor 7C (Black, 32 GB),)

while i run the above code it just gives me empty parenthesis

I think so that something is wrong with my regex so anyone please help me

THANKING IN ADVANCE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean this? This will look for the `"name"` and take everything within the next quotes as the `name` regex group.

`(.*?)` means everything until the first occurrence of `"`.

```
import re

see = """https://www.flipkart.com/honor-7c-blue-64-gb/p/itmfaybh5jjzhmpz?pid=MOBF3T87CECXMZQH&lid=LSTMOBF3T87CECXMZQHFPGOZQ&marketplace=FLIPKART","name":"Honor 7C (Blue, 64 GB)"},{"@type":"ListItem","position":2,"url":"https://www.flipkart.com/honor-7c-blue-32-gb/p/itmf53qmmggh2ynj?pid=MOBF3T87QFSQXGCM&lid=LSTMOBF3T87QFSQXGCMUHVDHM&marketplace=FLIPKART","name":"Honor 7C (Blue, 32 GB)"},{"@type":"ListItem","position":3,"url":"https://www.flipkart.com/honor-7c-black-32-gb/p/itmf5ch2zb97avvz?pid=MOBF3T877EEKFWGN&lid=LSTMOBF3T877EEKFWGN9WQ3A4&marketplace=FLIPKART","name":"Honor 7C (Black, 32 GB)"},{"@type":"ListItem","position":4,"url":"https://www.flipkart.com/honor-8c-black-64-gb/p/itmfc8c4fsekrpdp?pid=MOBFC8C8FXXNHZ7C&lid=LSTMOBFC8C8FXXNHZ7CZYQGKP&marketplace=FLIPKART"""
regex = r'\"name\":\"(?P<name>.*?)\"'
print(re.findall(regex, see))
# ['Honor 7C (Blue, 64 GB)', 'Honor 7C (Blue, 32 GB)', 'Honor 7C (Black, 32 GB)']
```